# Is it possible to be in violation of 18 USC 2339 accidentally?

Tags: united-states, israel, terrorism, freedom-of-press

During its military operation to reduce Hamas' military capabilities, Israeli airforce destroyed an office complex in Gaza.  Israel has claimed that it had absolutely certain information that Hamas' military targets were housed in that building.  The building was an office building with a number of tenants.  Among them were offices of the Associated Press news agency.

This has caused a controversy.  While AP acknowledges that they have been warned of the impending attack on the building and have been given time to evacuate, they maintain that they have had no knowledge of any Hamas properties or personal in the building.  Because Hamas is a *designated* terrorist organization, [18 USC 2339](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2339) may be applicable.

From my reading of [2339](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2339) (Harboring or concealing terrorists), AP may be exposed unless they have had firm knowledge that no part of the building was used by Hamas.  The problem is that, as a news agency reporting on military activities around the entire globe, it strains credulity to suggest that they would not be aware of Hamas operating in the same building with them.

If Israel can provide evidence, which can be certified as genuine by the FBI, that Hamas did operate out of that same building, would that lead to a criminal exposure for AP?  Would the issue of whether they actually knew have to be decided at trial or would it even matter?

Comment: My understanding of such laws is that even if they were aware of Hamas's presence and failed to report it, that wouldn't rise to the level of "harboring and concealing".  Similar to "aiding and abetting" laws, it requires some sort of action, not merely an omission.

Comment: @NateEldredge wouldn't willingly acting as human shields be an act of harboring?  It would be "willingly" because they have the option of moving.  Putting your body (on purpose) between a cop and a bank robber would be harboring the bank robber, would it not?

Comment: I think you'd have to prove that their primary intent in staying there was to shield Hamas.  If they had legitimate reasons to stay, from which Hamas incidentally happened to benefit in some way, I don't see the statute applying.

Comment: @NateEldredge ah.  that makes sense.  is there a reference that can outline this?  this probably can be the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it's kind of a guess at this point.  I don't have a clear reference offhand.  One source that's often useful is the US Attorney's Manual; there's a public version which may not be current but may still have worthwhile info.

Answer (score 6):

Mere co-occupancy as a fellow tenant of a building owned by a third-party, without more, does not amount to harboring or concealing, the action that the statute in question criminalizes. Mere inaction does not establish criminal liability under this statute. The statute does not require the AP to actively gather intelligence for the U.S. government, or to engage in conflict with the neighbors of its offices.

Comment: You are formally stating what would be AP's defense's claim.  But it revolves around the definition of "harboring".  I think everything else is satisfied.  The code only requires that AP "has reasonable grounds to believe" that Hamas is "about to commit".  How do you arrive at the boundaries of what is harboring?  What would be the absolute minimum action that would have to be taken to breach that boundary?

Answer (score 4):

No.

One cannot accidentally violate [18. U.S.C. § 2339](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2339), because "harboring or concealing" a terrorist implies deliberate actions. Although the terms are undefined in the statute, a court looking to interpret them would likely rely on the fairly rich body of case law surrounding the more general harboring-and-concealing statute, [18 U.S.C. § 1071](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1071).

There is little dispute that that statute requires that the defendant actually had a purpose to harbor or conceal the person in question. [*United States v. Lockhart*, 956 F.2d 1418, 1423 (7th Cir. 1992)](https://casetext.com/case/us-v-lockhart-10) ("[T]he government had to establish ... that Lockhart intended to prevent Mathews's discovery and arrest.")

Further, the Second Circuit -- where AP is headquartered -- also requires that the charge be based on "some *physical* act tending to the secretion of the body of the offender." [*United States v. Shapiro*, 113 F.2d 891, 893 (2d Cir. 1940)](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-shapiro-7).

And the courts will not accept the failure to disclose information as the basis for a conviction. [*United States v. Foy*, 416 F.2d 940, 941 (7th Cir. 1969)](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-foy-2) ("While there are many negative or passive acts which would fall within the statutory prohibition, we do not think that a failure to disclose the location of a fugitive is the type of assistance contemplated by ‘harbor and conceal’ as used in § 1071."). This policy has even greater force in the AP's case, where the allegation is that AP knew about Hamas operations but refused to report on them; because imposing liability based on that decision would be an "intrusion into the function of editors," it would likely run afoul of the First Amendment. [*Miami Herald Publishing Co. v. Tornillo*, 418 U.S. 241, 258 (1974)](https://casetext.com/case/miami-herald-publishing-co-v-tornillo).

Separately, it is unlikely that these facts could support a conviction, as the statute does not care about the third party's designation as a terrorist, but rather asks whether the third party has committed one of the enumerated offenses. I'm not any kind of expert on Hamas, but I'm not confident that it's committed any of those offenses, which I believe are all focused on attacks against the United States, rather than any foreign nation. (Perhaps incidental injuries to Americans in Israel would be sufficient, though.)

Comment: I understand and agree with what you are saying about failure to report.  I think it's fairly accepted that the press does not have to *disclose* criminals' locations.  What I am curious about is failure to move.  It's analogous to a failure to move (or even to deliberately putting one's body) between a cop and a bank robber because, by being present in the building, AP (allegedly) acted as human shields for Hamas.  And I don't mean failure to move after being notified of an imminent attack.  I mean failure to move much earlier - as soon as they learned that Hamas utilized the building.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for Hamas to have committed any offenses to any individuals or assets directly linked to the US for the statute to apply simply because Hamas is *designated* as a terrorist organization.  This justifies the opinion that harming the United States is within the range of its *potential* activities.

Comment: Also if it is discovered that the AP claims, that they didn't know that Hamas used that building, have been a lie, that would point to a consciousness of guilt.   BTW, I am upvoting because the reference you gave did provide some pointers on how "harboring" maybe interpreted.

Comment: I think you're making too much of the terrorist designation. There are certain statutes that govern how one can interact with a designated terrorist group, but I don't think section 2339 is one of them. It explicitly requires that the terrorist is engaged in one of those enumerated offenses, so there isn't really any way of getting around that. That list of offenses is as critical to determining liability as the definition of "harboring."

Comment: 2339 does say "is about to commit". So that would support what you are saying (that a mere designation doesn't cover it).